# How to recover lost commit with git?

Tags: git

I lost important changes and don't know what happened to them.

I did `git add` on the files I wanted to add.
I then did `git commit -m`

I then did another add and commit. Then I pulled latest onto master branch and then merged the branch with the commits into my master and the changes were gone. "Grid system additions" is the commit that is missing. I need it back.

I have pasted what happened below:

```bash
$ git status
# On branch mp_grid
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   Assets/MarkScratchPad.unity
#   modified:   Assets/Resources/GamePiece.prefab
#   modified:   Assets/Scripts/Grid/GridManager.cs
#   modified:   Assets/Scripts/Services/NotificationCenter.cs
#   modified:   ProjectSettings/EditorBuildSettings.asset

$ git add Assets/Scripts/Grid/Gridmanager.cs
$ git add assets/resources/gamepiece.prefab
$ git add assets/scripts/services/notificationcenter.cs
$ git add projectsettings/editorbuildsettings.asset
$ git add assets/markscratchpad.unity
$ git commit -m "Grid system additions"
# On branch mp_grid
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   Assets/MarkScratchPad.unity
#   modified:   Assets/Resources/GamePiece.prefab
#   modified:   Assets/Scripts/Grid/GridManager.cs
#   modified:   Assets/Scripts/Services/NotificationCenter.cs
#   modified:   ProjectSettings/EditorBuildSettings.asset
$ git add Assets/MarkScratchPad.unity
$ git commit -m "More updates"
[mp_grid bfd3bb3] More updates
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git merge mp_grid
```

Comment: check git reflog to see if you can find it there. If so you can merge it by hash

Comment: it is not there. i tried that

Comment: git fsck --lost-found did not find the commit either

Comment: Did it actually make the commit? Right after you did the commit, it spit out a list of modified files not staged for commit, and it's the entire list you tried to add. Looking over the two lists, you have mismatches in capitalizations. You also appear to be on a Mac, which IIRC is case-sensitive. I think you didn't actually add anything for commit, because you didn't match the capitalizations.

Comment: OSX is case sensitive. You thus never added or committed your changes.

Comment: Do you have Time Machine backups enabled? Can you recover from that?

Comment: I didn't know OSX was case sensitive. A costly lesson well learned.

Comment: @katneps Not to rub it in, but, when `git status` does not show any added files after trying to add them, you should get very suspicious. And after the second round of editing, `git status` still showing the files as just "modified" should *really* get you thinking.